# Copy my documents without rename in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, xcopy, robocopy

All,
Occasionally I use xcopy or robocopy to copy my documents folder as a backup. The issue is no matter what I name it, say MD_Backup, Windows always renames it to My Documents. I'd really like it to not do that. Anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really a programming question, nudging over to SU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is a hidden file within the `My Documents` folder named `desktop.ini` that is telling Windows that the folder is special and should always be named `My Documents` even though the folder name on disk may be different.

Deleting the `desktop.ini` file should revert the folder to the name you are expecting to see. You may need to enable viewing [hidden files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/show-hidden-files) as well as system files (in the same place as enabling hidden files).

After you delete the file you'll want to re-hide system files at least in order to not see the `desktop.ini` files on your desktop and everywhere else.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, Mokubai!

I recently got a new SSD, installed an almost-fresh Win7 on it (restored from a backup which I'd made from when the old HDD installation was fresh). I moved the HDD to 2nd SATA connector (though it'll still boot, if necessary). Then I made a temporary admin user ID on the SSD installation, and used it to redirect my Documents, Downloads & Videos folders to the corresponding folders on the HDD, via Junctions, like this: "cd \Users\Dave", "ren Videos Videos_SSD". "mklink /j Videos F:\Users\Dave\Videos" etc.. But Explorer was confused. Your advice fixed it.